# Only pull from SQL if 2 conditions are met

Tags: php, sql

I have a if statement which pulls all parent locations in my 'locations' table, and another table with my categories.

I want to only display the location if there is a category in it, at the moment it still displays the location if the category is empty. I have tried a number of ways and it is not working, see below the original which I was editing.

```
<?php 
    if(!empty($loc_c)){   
        $i = 1;
        foreach($loc_c as $c){ 
            $sql = "select * from location where parent_id  = {$c['id']}";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            $loc_ci = $Manager->fetchAssoc($result);
?>
```

Comment: Since this is only an sql question - it would be a good idea to only write sql in it. You should state the schema/relationship between the two tables. and "the number of ways" you've already tried to do it (and what happened).

Comment: How about adding to your query: `AND Category IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 0):

`$sql = "select * from location l where exists ( select from categories c where ... ) and parent_id  = {$c['id']}";`

replace the ... with the predicate for how location and categories are related.

Also, consider replacing the loop in php with a join in sql